# How do I find out if the current AUTH cookie is "permanent"?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have a ASP.NET website where after a specific user action, I have to issue a new AUTH cookie almost identical to the one the user already currently has. I'm having trouble finding out whether the current AUTH cookie is supposed to be persisted or not. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cookie expiration isn't set, then it's session.

If you are trying to discover it's life via the browser, you can use firebug with the firecookie plugin. Or the web developer tool will also enumerate all the cookies on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Any cookie that is not session will have Expires field. If you send it into feature date - you will get it "permanent" until the time expires. If you want to maintain "permanent" cookie status you would refresh it on next user login and shift it further into the future. One month is usually enough